# How to change the text through JS without having class and id?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

There are a couple of `<text>` blocks in the code which have identical class names. In these blocks, there are `<tspan>` tags. I need to change the letter in the `<tspan>` tags from “a” to “p” for each `<text>` block.

Block itself:

```
<text class="deal-label--text" transform="translate(8, 17)" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, &quot;Liberation Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600;">
    <tspan style="font-family: symbol-olymp, &quot;Open Sans&quot;;">a</tspan>
    <tspan dx="1px">1000</tspan>
</text>
<text class="deal-label--text" transform="translate(8, 17)" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, &quot;Liberation Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600;">
    <tspan style="font-family: symbol-olymp, &quot;Open Sans&quot;;">a</tspan>
    <tspan dx="1px">2000</tspan>
</text>
</text>
<text class="deal-label--text" transform="translate(8, 17)" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, &quot;Liberation Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600;">
    <tspan style="font-family: symbol-olymp, &quot;Open Sans&quot;;">a</tspan>
    <tspan dx="1px">3000</tspan>
</text>
```

Comment: Please show us the js you already wrote to attempt addressing the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look for that tag inside the known class

Comment: Will the tspan with the `a` always be the first one in the list of tspans inside the `<text>` element?

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all of `text` elements and iterate over all of them with `forEach`. http://jsfiddle.net/t2gbd6wk/

Comment: Neither `text` nor `tspan` are valid HTML elements. If they are meant to be custom elements, they're also invalid. Custom elements must have a dash `-` in the name.

Comment: @connexo think svg

Comment: The question is not tagged svg, and it doesn't mention svg either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use combinators of `querySelector`. The query `.deal-label--text:nth-child(1)` means elements which are the first children of elements with `deal-label--text` class. `document.querySelectorAll` returns the pseudo array has every HTML element object that matches the query. You can convert the pseudo array into the real array with `Array.from` method and you can work on each value in array with `.forEach` method.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.deal-label--text:nth-child(1)')).forEach(element => element.innerText = 'p');
```

Comment: Thank you, and now how to replace all the elements? The querySelectorAll selector does not work.

Comment: @euppi98 I changed the answer to be able to replace all the elements. Check it out.